# how to calculate ANSI CRC16 polynomial (0x8005) in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, crc, crc16

I tried to calculate ANSI CRC16 polynomial (0x8005) using this code

```
import crcmod
crc16 = crcmod.mkCrcFun(0x8005, 0xffff, True)
```

but I got this error message

> ValueError: The degree of the polynomial must be 8, 16, 24, 32 or 64

Comment: I got the same error message " ValueError: The degree of the polynomial must be 8, 16, 24, 32 or 64"

Comment: It seems like `0x8005` is **not** the valid representation for CRC16. That's what the error is telling you: `0x8005` represents a CRC that has an unsupported degree. Change it to something meaningful.

Comment: I am trying to calculate crc16 for ext4 file system and based on the docs it uses 0x8005 https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Metadata_Checksums#Block_Groups

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an implied `1` at the beginning of `0x8005`

crcmod expects you to provide the `1` explicitly

```
import crcmod
crc16 = crcmod.mkCrcFun(0x18005, 0xffff, True)
```